# Как сделать чтобы при нажатие на кнопку -карта обновлялась, а не создавалась еще одна на js

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы при нажатие на кнопку -карта обновлялась, а не создавалась еще одна на js? Я смотрел документацию, но что то не понял как сделать обновление. Сейчас у меня при нажатие создается еще одна карта. Буду рад любой помощи!

```js
document.querySelector("#a2").addEventListener("click",function(){
var mapa="Казань ,Магистральная 10";
init();   

})




document.querySelector("#a").addEventListener("click",function(){
var mapa="Москва, улица Василия Петушкова, 3с1";
init();   
});


function init(){
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
        zoom: 9,
        // Добавим панель маршрутизации.
        controls: ['routePanelControl']
    });
    
 // Создаем геообъект с типом геометрии "Точка".
myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
            // Описание геометрии.
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [55.8, 37.8]
            },
            // Свойства.
            properties: {
                // Контент метки.
                iconContent: '',
                hintContent: ''
            }
        });
        myMap.geoObjects
        .add(myGeoObject);
    var control = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');
  
    // Зададим состояние панели для построения машрутов.
    control.routePanel.state.set({
        // Тип маршрутизации.
        type: 'masstransit',
        // Выключим возможность задавать пункт отправления в поле ввода.
        fromEnabled: false,
        // Адрес или координаты пункта отправления.
        from: mapa,
        // Включим возможность задавать пункт назначения в поле ввода.
        toEnabled: true
        // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
        //to: 'Петербург'
    });

    // Зададим опции панели для построения машрутов.
    control.routePanel.options.set({
        // Запрещаем показ кнопки, позволяющей менять местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
        allowSwitch: false,
        // Включим определение адреса по координатам клика.
        // Адрес будет автоматически подставляться в поле ввода на панели, а также в подпись метки маршрута.
        reverseGeocoding: true,
        // Зададим виды маршрутизации, которые будут доступны пользователям для выбора.
        types: { masstransit: true, pedestrian: true, taxi: true }
    });

    // Создаем кнопку, с помощью которой пользователи смогут менять местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
    var switchPointsButton = new ymaps.control.Button({
        data: {content: "Поменять местами", title: "Поменять точки местами"},
        options: {selectOnClick: false, maxWidth: 160}
    });
    // Объявляем обработчик для кнопки.
    switchPointsButton.events.add('click', function () {
        // Меняет местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
        control.routePanel.switchPoints();
    });
    //myMap.controls.add(switchPointsButton);
});}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Маршрут от точки на карте</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=2ca7f88e-79a8-4b7f-bd55-b47b2bf5f3fd" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="route_panel_control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 80%;
            height: 80%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="a2">Адрес1</button>
    <button id="a">Адрес</button>
<div style="position: absolute;" id="map"></div>

</body>
<style>
.display-none{
    display:none;
}

</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Кроме метода `init`, который именно создаёт карту, нужны и другие методы, которые будут её обновлять.